# MySQL+Sphinx only one index works,while the others don‘t

Tags: mysql, sphinx

I have created the indexes,the below is the information:

```
indexing index 'acdphotos'...
collected 0 docs, 0.0 MB
total 0 docs, 0 bytes
total 0.065 sec, 0 bytes/sec, 0.00 docs/sec
indexing index 'acdphotos_delta'...
collected 0 docs, 0.0 MB
total 0 docs, 0 bytes
total 0.033 sec, 0 bytes/sec, 0.00 docs/sec
indexing index 'acdusers'...
collected 11 docs, 0.0 MB
sorted 0.0 Mhits, 99.1% done
total 11 docs, 311 bytes
total 0.008 sec, 34736 bytes/sec, 1228.63 docs/sec
indexing index 'acdalbums'...
collected 0 docs, 0.0 MB
total 0 docs, 0 bytes
total 0.006 sec, 0 bytes/sec, 0.00 docs/sec
total 2 reads, 0.000 sec, 4.1 kb/call avg, 0.1 msec/call avg
total 19 writes, 0.001 sec, 1.2 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
```

but when i try to search something,only the users can return some results, while the photos and albums returns nothing.BTW,the "acdphotos_delta" is an incremental index base on "acdphotos".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the line:

```
collected 0 docs, 0.0 MB
```

It mean nothing was indexed.
Check your sql_query and make sure that it fetch some data from database.

Comment: Thank u Yaroslav, i have checked the database,it's empty....so there is nothing to be indexed. Thanks for advice!